# How to limit the number of files in a directory?

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, filesystems, file-copy

Is it even possible to limit the number (and not the size) of files in a specific directory?

My directory only can contain up to five files, and `cp file_6 mydir` must not be allowed.

Comment: Nope,  this is not something that will be enforced by the OS.  Not without writing your own filesystem (e.g. with FUSE), in any case.   The most likely reason for this would be that nobody else actually wants a bizarre anti-feature like this.  If you want this but don't want to write your own fs, you'll have to check for the number of files in whatever program you've written to write files into the directory.  or, e.g., wrap `cp` in a script or function to do the check.  and accept the fact that the "limit" will only apply to programs that perform this check.

Comment: Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here. [Edit] the question if there is.

Comment: @cas Sure there is: `quota` is the very definition of limiting disk usage in any kind of way.

Comment: a directory is not a filesystem.  `quota` is applied to entire mounted filesystems, not to single directories contained by them.

Comment: @cas XFS would offer project-based quotas, i.e. for directories.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `quota` and limit the number of inodes, so no more files could be created.
To realize this, the simplest way (IMHO) is to set the directory to a specific group say `quotagroup`.

Step by step, all done by `root` (or use `sudo`):

**1. Install quota**

`quota` should be represented in all standard repositories, use your default package manager.

**2. Add quotaoption to mount**

Edit `/etc/fstab` and add group quota in the mount options, e.g. for a separated `home` (focus on the `grpquota`-part):

```
UUID=ab123-cd45-ef67 /home  ext4  defaults,grpquota 0 1
```

Run `mount -a` to apply this, or use `mount -o remount,grpquota /home`

**3. Activate quota**

```
quotacheck -cgv /home
```

Will `-c`reate the quota control file (`aquota.group`) for `-g`roup quotas at the mount point level of the respective device. Be `-v`erbose

```
quotaon -gv /home
```

Activate quota checking. `-gv` as above.

**4. Create limited group, adapt directoy settings**

```
addgroup quotagroup
chgrp quotagroup /home/dir/to/limit
chmod g+s /home/dir/to/limit
```

Will create the (to be) limited group `quotagroup`, change group ownership of the respective directory to `quotagroup` and make sure that new files in the directory have the same group ownership as the parent (`g+s` = "set gid-bit").

**5. Define quota**

```
edquota -g quotagroup /home
```

allows editing the quota settings. Looks something like this:

```
Disk quotas for group quotatest (gid 1003):
Filesystem blocks  soft  hard  inodes  soft  hard
/dev/sda2       4     0     0       3     0     0
```

Where `blocks` defines used blocks followed by soft and hard quotas for blocks, and inodes shows currently used inodes followed by the limits.

Set the hard limit for inodes to `6` - one for the directory itself and five for the five files.
Soft limits are used to temporarily allow exceeding the limit for a given period of time. The current in-use values may not be altered!

**6. Limitations, problems, comments**

- One would need a separate quota + special group for each of such directories.
- `root` is not limited by quota.
- Quota acts on the whole mount point, not just a specific directory, i.e. this cannot be applied for directories.
- Again: Any file in `/home` with group `quotagroup` will be counted in the quota - no matter if in your limited directory or not.
- `XFS` is a filesystem that allows project quotas, i.e. quotas for a project in a directory. If you have the possibility, you might prefer that, especially for many of such cases.
- Alternatively to a full `XFS`-device, a virtual (loopback) one might be helpful.

Comment: Good solution; I was trying to create filesystems with limited inodes, but kept hitting minimums (128), which meant hacky workarounds like pre-defining filler files in 
a hidden directory somewhere.